# jquery parsing rel attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes, rel

For 1 param in rel I use:

```
<a rel="all">All</a> 
var group = $(this).attr('rel');
```

How to extract multiple rel attribute from link?

```
<a rel="all test1 test2">All</a>
```

TNQ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var groups = group.split( ' ' );
```

See this [test](http://jsfiddle.net/9a4mf/).

Or, if you want to account for possible repeated whitespace chars in between them

```
var groups = group.split( /\s+/ );
```